# how to get all users connected to default user without going through login page?

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle, fosrestbundle, fosoauthserverbundle

I want to secure my API with FOSUserBundle (and avoid the use of FOSOAuthServerBundle due to lack of documentation with complete example).

To make my API secure, I just created firewalls as follows:

```
firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern:       ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security:      false
    api_doc:
        pattern:      ^/api/doc
        security:     false
    main:
        pattern: ^/
        form_login:
            provider: fos_userbundle
            csrf_token_generator: security.csrf.token_manager
        logout:       true
        anonymous:    true

access_control:
    - { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY } 
    - { path: ^/api, roles: [ IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY ] } 
    - { path: ^/admin/, roles: [ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN]}
```

This is great! But this requires that every one has to be connected before using the website so that I can display the list of ads, etc. *( Even GET queries needs a connected for security purpose)*

To overcome, I am thinking about having all the users connected with a "default" user with limited privileges (just enough for simple querying without posting).

Is it possible to do so?

Thanks for your help.

**PS:** I did manage to get FOSUserBundle and FOSOAuthServerBundle working together. In fact, I was able to create a client  and get an access token for it through command lines. But, I was not able to config the `security.yml` properly so that I get a login page that returns an access token.

Comment: does the Oauth solution meet your needs and its just the config you need help with?

Comment: I did not manage to find a good documentation for configuring `security.yml. If you have a good doc on that I will be happy!

Comment: One more thing, the API will be only my website! No third party is involved

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the symfony entry on [How to Authenticate Users with API Keys](http://symfony.com/doc/current/security/api_key_authentication.html). The entry has most of the code that you need and is well documented.

You do have to add a field for the API key in your `fos_user` table e.g.

```
ALTER TABLE fos_user ADD api_key VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL;
```

You also need to correctly implement the `ApiKeyUserProvider::getUsernameForApiKey` to look up in your database for the user based on the given API key, something like this:

```
$repository = $this->manager->getRepository('Application\UserBundle\Entity\User');
$user = $repository->findOneBy(array('apiKey' => $apiKey));
return empty($user) ? $user : $user->getUsername();
```

I implemented this a few years ago, it was simple to follow and has worked great!

Comment: Let me know how it turned out.